# Failure while removing unwanted packages/configurations/dependencies

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, policy

I have a minor problem which occurs everytime I'm installing a new application. Basically there must be some unused packages/configurations/dependencies which make some troubles.
What happens is, that after the successful installation of the **wanted** package/application the system tries to setup/install the **unwanted** packages/configurations/dependencies, which will always fail.

Example:

This is what happens when I install something using

```
sudo apt-get install
```

Output in terminal:

```
bzad@bzad-Ideapad-S205:~$ sudo apt-get install tcc
[sudo] password for bzad: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
tcc is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up vrmcamlab (3.5.0.0) ...
sudo: unknown user: lost+found
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
dpkg: error processing package vrmcamlab (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of vrmagic-linux-pc-camera-runtime:
 vrmagic-linux-pc-camera-runtime depends on vrmcamlab (= 3.5.0.0); however:
  Package vrmcamlab is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package vrmagic-linux-pc-camera-runtime (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 vrmcamlab
 vrmagic-linux-pc-camera-runtime
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried to use the standard clean-up terminal-lines

```
sudo apt-get autoremove

dpkg -l | grep ^rc | cut -d ' ' -f3 | xargs sudo apt-get purge -y
```

but they ended up with the same error messages. I hope this is not a duplicate somehow and I appreciate anybody who can give me a hint how I can get rid of these bodies in my ubuntu cellar.

Thanks in advance

PS: This must have happen while I tried to install the vrmagic driver packages for their stereo cameras

Behsad Ghanei

EDITS:

While going through the steps of `@mchid` an error occurs. Executing the following line

```
sh -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/vrmcamlab.postinst configure 3.5.0.0
```

yields

```
bzad@bzad-Ideapad-S205:~$ sh -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/vrmcamlab.postinst configure 3.5.0.0
+ [ configure = configure ]
+ SRC_FILE=/etc/skel/Desktop/vrmagic-camlab.desktop
+ ls /home
+ sudo -H -u bzad xdg-desktop-icon install /etc/skel/Desktop/vrmagic-camlab.desktop
+ sudo -H -u lost+found xdg-desktop-icon install /etc/skel/Desktop/vrmagic-camlab.desktop
sudo: unknown user: lost+found
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: Thankyou. It looks like you have a file /home/lost+found. Is there anything in this folder you need? If not, you should delete this folder.

Comment: You can run `sudo rm -R /home/lost+found` to delete the file.

Comment: That worked. I thought the folder is a recovery folder with hidden data which shouldn't be deleted. Anyway if you answer with that I will happily confirm it for yo and edit the other comments so the issue gets more clarified. Thank you

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Upon further inspection, it appears you have a file that shouldn't be there. Run the following commands to fix the problem:

```
sudo rm -R /home/lost+found
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I have left the previous instructions below although, it looks like they are not needed.

---

**previous instructions, probably not needed:**

Download the "Software for USB Components" zip package from https://www.vrmagic.com/imaging/downloads/ to your ~/Downloads folder and unzip the file.

Then, run the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg -P vrmcamlab 
sudo dpkg -P vrmagic-linux-pc-camera-runtime
sudo apt-get install gdebi
cd ~/Downloads/VRmUsbCamDevKitForLinuxX64_4.5.0
sudo gdebi ./vrmagic-linux-pc-camera-runtime_4.5.0_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi ./vrmagic-linux-pc-camera-sdk-4.5.0_4.5.0_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi ./libvrmusbcam2_3.5.0.0_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi ./vrmcamlab_3.5.0.0_amd64.deb
```

You can also install:

```
sudo gdebi ./vrmcamserver_3.5.0.0_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi ./vrmhotplug_3.5.0.0_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi ./vrmusbcamnet_3.5.0.0_all.deb
```

Please post any errors.

Comment: Please run the following command and post the output in your answer: `sh -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/vrmcamlab.postinst configure 3.5.0.0`